# Specify a non-release version of gem package in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

How do I specify a non-release version of a gem in rails?

I am continually making modifications to gem which I wish to test in my rails application.  What is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to approach this is to specify the location of a git repository rather than a version of the gem.

For example

```
gem "gem_name", git: "git://github.com/your_github/gem_name.git"
```

specifying your local machine

```
gem "gem_name", git: "/path/to/repository"
```

Alternatively you can simply specify the path

```
gem "gem_name", path: "/path/to/gemfile"
```

but usage of a git repository allows you to keep multiple configuration in alternate
branches, specify previous commits, and a lot more than I am able to describe in this short answer.  For example, the follows specifies an alternate branch:

```
gem "gem_name", git: "git://github.com/your_github/gem_name.git", branch: "branch_name"
```

See [here](http://gembundler.com/git.html) for more details.